# Как считать из файла только строку на английском языке, если строк несколько?

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

Как именно задать условие проверки строки на наличие латинских букв?

Comment: Проверьте символы в ней. Если найдете символ `(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')` , то латинские буквы в ней есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

предлагаю такой вариант поиска

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main(){

regex reg("[A-Za-z]");
string str="123a34";

if(regex_search(str,reg))
    cout << "string object matched\n";

}
```

в регулярном выражении пишем, что нас интересуют только латинские буквы, если if сработал, то буквы содержатся в строке

если вам надо что бы в строке были только латинские буквы, тогда так

```
regex reg("[^A-Za-z]");
string str="aasdasd4";

if(regex_search(str,reg))
    cout << "string have something wrong\n";
```

теперь если сработает if то в строке есть еще что то кроме букв

Comment: вопрос вот еще в чем, как найти в файле строку с латинскими буквами и вывести ее. Были попытки записать так как в вашем примере, но выводит не то что нужно

Comment: В строке должны быть только латинские буквы? Или они там могут встречатся? Приведите пример валидной и не валидной строки. После этошо посмотрим почему не правильно работало. Ну и не помешал бы ваш код, который выводит не то что надо