# Считать строку с латинскими буквами из файла

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

Нужно открыть файл и считать из него только строку с латинскими буквами и вывести ее. Не знаю как задать условие, что бы считывалась только эта строка.

Здесь считывается только первая строка и выводится, но не проверяет на условие

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <regex>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    regex reg("[^A-Za-z]");
    regex reg2("[^А-яа-я]");
    string s; 
    ifstream file("D:\\WE.txt"); 
    getline(file,s);
    if (regex_search(s, reg))
    {
        cout << s;
    }
    else cout << "no";

    file.close(); 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вот строка "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." — она на английском или нет?

Comment: @Yaant да, корректнее будет написать - строку с латинскими буквами. И все же как?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как считать из файла только строку на английском языке, если строк несколько?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900058/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be)

Comment: @VTT это не ответ на вопрос

Comment: Правильно, это ссылка на дубликат (который уже)

Answer (score 0):

отвечал уже на этот же вопрос, но отвечу еще раз

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    regex reg("[^A-Za-z ]");
    ifstream in("F://test.txt");

    string str="";
    while(getline(in, str)){
        if(!regex_search(str,reg))
            cout << str << endl;
        }
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

вот мой вывод и вот мой файл[image: введите сюда описание изображения]